# How do i emit an event from child svelte component without showing contents of child component?

Tags: svelte

Suppose i dispatch an event from a child component using createEventDispatcher, and i have some content in it, i want to receive this event but not want to show the contents of the child in parent, how to do that in svelte? Why is Reading and emitting so tightly coupled?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Maybe there is a better approach.

Comment: I Wanted to reduce code in one of the components for composability purposes and I didnt want to create a seperate component just for event emitting.So I put it in another less dense component. Should i proceed to create a component explicitly for event emitting?

Comment: An example could be helpful. You might not need a component at all, you can create events decoupled from component instances, e.g. by creating an instance of `EventTarget` and setting it as a context, it can be used to communicate between things. Creating a component just for events sounds like you are doing *something* wrong.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the direction I want to go into. I didnt know about this as I have just started front-end.